# Prolog Find the sum of integers between two integers

Tags: prolog

I am using GNU-Prolog trying to write a program that accepts `N` and `M` positive integers and sums all numbers between `N` and `M` , including `N` and `M`.

my code is:

```
findnum(N, N, M).    
findnum(N, M, Res) :- N1 is N+1, N1 < M, findnum(N1, M, Res), Res is N1 + M.
```

Execution only returns "no" with no answer, any idea what's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with

```
findnum(N, N, N).    

findnum(N, M, Res) :-
   N1 is N+1,
   N < M,
   findnum(N1, M, R0),
   Res is R0 + N.
```

Your first clause

```
findnum(N, N, M).
```

is wrong because you have to set (to unify) `M` to a value; and if you want sum numbers from `N` to `N`, the sum is `N`, so

```
findnum(N, N, N).
```

The idea for the second clause is to sum `N` to the sum from `N+1` to `M`; I see three errors in your implementation:

1) you have to call the terminal clause (`findnum(N, N, N)`) so is wrong the guard `N1 < M` because you have to call the terminal clause when `N1` is equal to `M`; the correct guard is `N < M` or `N1 <= M`

2) if your recursive call to `findnum/3` use, for the third argument, the same variable (`Res`), you can't add `N`, so you have to call with another variable: `R0` in my example

3) `Res is N1 + M` is wrong; the correct version is `Res is R0 + N`; the current number (`N`) plus the sum from `N+1` to `M`.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this probably isn't helpful but I just have to say it.

```
sums_upto(N, Sums) :- succ(N, N1), Sums is N * N1 / 2.

findnum(N, M, Total) :- 
  N < M,
  sums_upto(N, NSum), 
  sums_upto(M, MSum), 
  Total is N + MSum - NSum.
```